# Where clause condition on aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following simple query,

```
SELECT US_LOGON_NAME as Username, 
COUNT(I.IS_ISSUE_NO) as Issues
FROM ISSUES I JOIN USERS U ON I.IS_ASSIGNED_USER_ID = U.US_USER_ID
WHERE I.IS_RECEIVED_DATETIME BETWEEN 20110101000000 AND 20110107000000
GROUP BY U.US_LOGON_NAME;
```

Where I want to add additional COUNT() functions to the select list but impose certain where conditions on them. Is this done with a CASE() statement somehow? I tried putting Where clauses inside the select list, and that doesn't seem to be allowed. I'm not sure if subqueries are really necessary here, but I dont think so.

For example I want one COUNT() function that only counts issues within a certain range, then another in another range or with other assorted conditions, etc:

```
 SELECT US_LOGON_NAME as Username, 
 COUNT(I.IS_ISSUE_NO (condition here)
 COUNT(I.IS_ISSUE_NO (a different condition here)
```

etc...

Still grouped by Logon Name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN I.IS_ISSUE_NO (condition here) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COND1
  SUM(CASE WHEN I.IS_ISSUE_NO (condition here) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COND2
```

Comment: Does not `COUNT` also count `0`?  I thought only `NULL` was not counted.

Comment: @Kirk Woll: Where does it say COUNT in his answer?

Comment: Yes, but Adam isn't COUNTing, he's SUMming.

Comment: @Mark, nowhere, curse me for lazy reading. :)

Answer (score 5):

A couple of solutions.

You can take advantage of the fact that SQL does not COUNT NULL values:

```
  SELECT US_LOGON_NAME as Username, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN <cond>       THEN I.IS_ISSUE_NO ELSE NULL END)
  COUNT(CASE WHEN <other cond> THEN I.IS_ISSUE_NO ELSE NULL END)
  . . .
```

Or you can use SUM instead of COUNT:

```
  SELECT US_LOGON_NAME as Username, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN <cond>       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  SUM(CASE WHEN <other cond> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  . . .
```

In either case, you can repeat as many times as you need to.

Comment: I think your `CASE` expressions are probably invalid syntax because there is no `END`.

Comment: I think you are correct, sir.  I just updated the syntax.  Must stop rushing.

Answer (score 0):

The example returns count per user, per `IssueType`.

```
;
with
q_00 as (
select
      is_issue_no
    , is_assigned_user_id 
    , case
          when is_issue_no between  1 and 10 then 'A'
          when is_issue_no between 11 and 14 then 'B'
          else  'C'  
      end as IssueType
from Issues 
)
select
      us_logon_name
    , IssueType
    , count(1) as cnt
from q_00  as a
join users as u on a.is_assigned_user_id = u.us_user_id
group by us_logon_name, IssueType
order by us_logon_name, IssueType ;
```

SQL server 2005 +