# What is best way to write query with multiple aggregate columns and multiple where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table **tbl_LEDGER**

```
+-----------+--------+-----+
| AccountId | GlCode | Amt |
+-----------+--------+-----+
| LAS00001  | INTRAC | 100 |
| LAS00002  | INTRAC | 150 |
| LAS00001  | INTLAS | 200 |
+-----------+--------+-----+
```

**Desired Result :**

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+
| AccountId | intractamt | intlasAmt |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
| LAS00001  |        100 |       200 |
| LAS00002  |        150 |         0 |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

**Here is my working query:**

```
select accountid,sum(amt) intracamt,  (select SUM(amt)  from tbl_LEDGER 
where   GLCode='intlas' and AccountID=intrac.AccountID ) intlasamt 
from tbl_LEDGER intrac 
where GLCode='intrac'    group by AccountID    order by AccountID
```

**Another Working query :**

```
select a.accountId,a.amt as 'RACAMT',b.amt as 'LACAMT' from 
(
select accountid ,glcode, SUM(amt) as amt from nbfcledger where GLCode='intrac' group by GLCode,AccountID 
) a
inner join 
(
select accountid ,glcode, SUM(amt) as amt from nbfcledger where GLCode='intlas'  group by GLCode,AccountID 
)b
on a.AccountID = b.AccountID order by AccountID
```

What are the other ways in which I can achieve the same result? Which one is best and why? I was hoping I could do this without PIVOT.

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server? Are there more differing values in GlCode?

Comment: @Shnugo I am using SQL Server 2008, yes there are more differing values in GlCode. Bu I am interested in just these two.

Comment: Any reason why you are trying to avoid `pivot`?

Comment: @sstan other than the fact that I already know that way and I dont like the syntax. No. If you want to post pivot as answer go ahead. It might help someone. If it is most efficient way. I would mark it as answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where clause condition on aggregate functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662955/where-clause-condition-on-aggregate-functions)

Answer (score 5):

```
select AccountId,
       Sum(case when GlCode = 'INTRAC' then amt else 0 end ) as intractamt,
       Sum(case when GlCode = 'INTLAS' then amt else 0 end ) as intlasAmt 
from tbl_LEDGER
group by AccountId
```

Another way to do the same is as given above.

Comment: definitely more efficient than the queries posted in the question.

Comment: @sstan I don't think so because above query takes around 5 seconds on my table and the one provided by me `select accountid,sum(amt) intracamt,  (select SUM(amt)  from tbl_LEDGER 
where   GLCode='intlas' and AccountID=intrac.AccountID ) intlasamt 
from tbl_LEDGER intrac 
where GLCode='intrac'    group by AccountID    order by AccountID` takes less than 1 second. Unless my query is returning result from cache

Comment: If `GLCode` has more values than just `INTRAC` and `INTLAS`, and depending on whether that column has an index, and depending on the values distribution of that column, it could be that the query needs a `WHERE` clause as well (`where GLCode in ('INTRAC', 'INTLAS')`).  Adding that filter certainly wouldn't hurt, and it could definitely help.  This is the only detail that would explain it being slower than the queries posted in the question, imo.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach:

```
 DECLARE @tbl_LEDGER TABLE(AccountId VARCHAR(100),GlCode VARCHAR(100),Amt DECIMAL(8,4));
 INSERT INTO @tbl_LEDGER VALUES
 ('LAS00001','INTRAC',100)
,('LAS00002','INTRAC',150)
,('LAS00001','INTLAS',200);

WITH IntracValues AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM @tbl_LEDGER
    WHERE GlCode='INTRAC'
)
,IntlasValues AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM @tbl_LEDGER
    WHERE GlCode='INTLAS'
)
SELECT IntracValues.AccountId
      ,ISNULL(IntracValues.Amt,0) AS intractAmt
      ,ISNULL(IntlasValues.Amt,0) AS intlasAmt
FROM IntracValues 
FULL OUTER JOIN IntlasValues ON IntracValues.AccountId=IntlasValues.AccountId
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you check this:

```
WITH DataSource ([AccountId], [Type], [Amount]) AS
(
    SELECT [AccountId]
           ,'intractamt'
           ,Sum(amt)
    FROM tbl_LEDGER
    WHERE [GlCode] = 'INTRAC'
    GROUP BY AccountId 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT AccountId
          ,'intlasAmt'
          ,Sum(amt) 
    FROM tbl_LEDGER
    WHERE [GlCode] = 'INTLAS'
    GROUP BY [AccountId]
)
SELECT [AccountId]
      ,[intractamt]
      ,[intlasAmt]
FROM DataSource
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Amount]) FOR [Type] IN ([intractamt], [intlasAmt])
) PVT
```

If you are not testing on production execute the queries with:

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
```

and use the following [site](http://www.statisticsparser.com/) to compare the statistics from the message tab.